# Как починить вёрстку в Safari?

Tags: вёрстка, safari, frontend

Верстаю свой первый сайт на заказ. https://kuraj-voyage.ru/content/expeditions.html . Работаю на windows, в гугле, опере, файрфоксе, яндексе всё выглядит примерно одинаково, но вот у заказчика макбук, и в safari всё выглядит очень печально. Если кратко вот как должно выглядеть и выглядит во всех браузерах кроме сафари

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот как в сафари(извиняюсь за качество, это прислал заказчик).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем все точки съехали, заданы они positions : absolute и выравнены margin'ом. Также во многих местах смещено позиционирование элементов и искажены тени. Попробовал добавить префиксы -webkit, но не помогло, выглядит всё также. Кто-нибудь может подсказать где искать проблему и как её решить?
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: «где искать проблему» — в Safari в инструментах разработчика, разумеется. Если не хотите приобретать мак (а надо бы) — то хотя бы виртуальную машину установите

Comment: Советую поставить образ macOS на VM (например VurtialBox) и потестить там.
А вообще, у меня видно проблемы какие-то: https://ibb.co/RvbLvr4 (Точки не прям на своих линиях)

Comment: sepera_okeq, Спасибо за ответ, а насчёт точек не на линиях ,это у заказчика в макете так.